# How to recreate this simple flowchart?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, flow-charts

This flowchart has given me nothing but pain and frustration. I've been trying to recreate it for a few days and not been able yet. I use the tikz package.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Since you tried something, could you post a minimal example of what you did so far?

Comment: Well my first attempt is using the node function while the second is using matrix. I don't really want to post my example as they cause 20 error messages.

Comment: You could try making a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe), that way it's easier for others to help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A wee bit more advance solution :-).

With use of Ti*k*Z libraries `arrows.meta`, `chains` and `positioning`, the image code become very concise. Image elements styles are collected in `tikzpicture` options, but can be written in document preamble (or in document body) using `\tikzset`:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 4mm and 2mm,
  start chain = A going below,
   arr/.style = {-Straight Barb},
   box/.style = {draw, text width=7em, align=center,
                 on chain, join=by arr}
                        ]
\node   [box]   {text 1};   % <--- node name: A-1
\node   [box]   {example of two lines long text};
\node   [box]   {text 3};
%
\node   (A-4)  [below right=of A-3] {text 4};
\draw[arr]  (A-3) |- (A-4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do you linebreak in text 4 using this method?

Comment: @Anon, it break automatically when it is longer than prescribed width of node (by `text width`). Now I see, that in code is older text in second node. I will correct this ASAP. I suggest you,  to start reading some documentation about `tikz`. At least part III of Ti*k*Z & PGF manual and by this make yourself more familiar with it.

Comment: But what about (A-4)? It doesn't have the [box] style.

Comment: @Anon, see package documentation: **Ti*k*Z $ PGF manual for version 3.1.9a** , chapter **13 Specifying Coordinates**, pages 136 -- 152, specifically section **13.3.1 Intersections of Perpendicular Lines** on page 144.

Comment: @Anon, please analyze MWE. The analysis should clearly show you that the last node is offset from the penultimate node by the distance between the nodes- Arrow between them is defined by  `\draw[arr]  (A-3) |- (A-4);`  where meaning of  `|-`  symbol is described in  section 13.3.1 Intersections of Perpendicular Lines as I noted in the previous comment.

Answer (score 6):

Using `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}


% Define block styles
\tikzset{block/.style={rectangle, draw, text width=5em, text centered, minimum height=4em}}
% Define line style
\tikzset{line/.style={draw, -latex'}}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
    \node [block] (bl1) {text 1};
    \node [block, below of=bl1, node distance=3cm] (bl2) {text 2};
    \node [block, below of=bl2, node distance=3cm] (bl3) {text 3};
    \node [below right of = bl3, node distance=3cm] (bl4) {text 4};
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (bl1) -- (bl2);
    \path [line] (bl2) -- (bl3);
    \path [line] (bl3) |- (bl4);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

---

Edit: [carlatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/101651/carlatex)'s suggestion: replaced `\tikzstyle` command

Comment: Thank you! I hope you have a nice day!

Comment: Also how do you add this to the code for more flat boxes?
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=none]

Comment: Try experimenting, with the code, in the `\tikzstyle` definition adjust the value for `minimum height`. Use the `\node` parameters to i.e. adjust the distance between the nodes.

Answer (score 1):

One of the advantages of plain TikZ is that beginners can guess the meaning of the code. Here is a simple way. The library `arrows.meta` provides a lot of arrow tips, see Section 16.5 Reference: Arrow Tips in [the PGF Manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={draw,minimum width=4cm,minimum height=1.2cm},>=Straight Barb,font=\sffamily]
\def\a{2}
\path
(0,0)     node[box] (SNC) {Hạt giống SNC}       
(0,-\a)   node[box] (NC) {Hạt giống NC}
(0,-2*\a) node[box] (XN) {Hạt giống XN}
;
\draw[->] (SNC)--(NC);
\draw[->] (NC)--(XN);
\draw[->] (XN)|-+(1.5*\a,-\a/2) node[right]{Sản xuất đại trà};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```